# how to extract the id field of this string in python

Tags: python, json, string

Hi i need to get the id field of this string.
I got i as an response from an rest api command executed with requests.
So if i enter response.json() it displays the following information:

```
[{'id': 28, 'testExecKey': 'ATSP-447', 'testKey': 'ATSP-446', 'status': 'TODO', 'type': 'Generic', 'defects': [], 'evidences': [], 'customFields': [], 'steps': [], 'assignee': 'Z659669', 'testEnvironments': [], 'iterations': []}]
```

if i set it

```
test = [{'id': 28, 'testExecKey': 'ATSP-447', 'testKey': 'ATSP-446', 'status': 'TODO', 'type': 'Generic', 'defects': [], 'evidences': [], 'customFields': [], 'steps': [], 'assignee': 'Z659669', 'testEnvironments': [], 'iterations': []}]
```

how do i extract the id number here 28 out of the data?
Thanks in advance

i tried the following :
test(1)
test[1]
test['id']

but it did not work

i would expect to get 28 as return value

Comment: `test[0]['id']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

test=[{'id': 28, 'testExecKey': 'ATSP-447', 'testKey': 'ATSP-446', 'status': 'TODO', 'type': 'Generic', 'defects': [], 'evidences': [], 'customFields': [], 'steps': [], 'assignee': 'Z659669', 'testEnvironments': [], 'iterations': []}]

print(test[0]["id"])